# Extending TableLayout class - adding rows

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I am trying to extend the TableLayout class, such that rows will be populated automatically by the class.  The issue I am having is the rows that I add inside the custom class do not display.

Ex. within the Activity:

```
private TextView getTableCell(String text) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(text);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    return tv;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DatasetTableLayout table = (DatasetTableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.addView(getTableCell("activity1"));
    tr.addView(getTableCell("activity2"));
    tr.addView(getTableCell("activity3"));
    table.addView(tr);
```

This successfully adds a row to the table.  However, within my custom class:

```
private TextView getTableCell(String text) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(text);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    return tv;
}

private void update() {
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(context);
    tr.addView(getTableCell("class1"));
    tr.addView(getTableCell("class2"));
    tr.addView(getTableCell("class3"));
    addView(tr);
}
```

*does not* successfully add a row.  Well, it does add a row, as getChildCount(), and getChildAt() do return this row - but it does not get displayed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have found the problem.  Inside DatasetTableLayout.getTableCell() (DatasetTableLayout extends TableLayout), the call new LayoutParams() creates a android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams object, when what I need is a android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.

Lesson learned - do not rely on Eclipse's organize imports command!!

Comment: it saves my life. you right any layoutparam doesnt work on tablelayout but talberow.layoutparam

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be something along this line: `addView(tr);` Does it successfully add your `TableRow` to `TableLayout`?

Edit:

```
TableLayout tb = new TableLayout(this);
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("row");
tr.addView(tv);
tb.addView(tr); // this is what I mean
setContentView(tb);
```

Your code for creating rows works fine, but if you haven't add it to the table, and later on, add the table to the parent view as well, your rows wouldn't get displayed.

Comment: See my answer below (can't seem to format text properly if I add a comment)

Comment: You can edit your original post. Anyway, what I mean is: you called addView(tr), but where to add it? Maybe that's why it's not getting displayed. You should get a reference to the row you want to update, and then call the addView(tr).

Comment: It was successfully being added to the table via the addView(tr); statement in update().  The problem was with the LayoutParams (see comment on original post).

Answer (score 0):

@theresia (Can't seem to format text if I add a comment):
It does appear that it adds the TableRow:

```
for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
    TableRow row = (TableRow) getChildAt(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < row.getChildCount(); j++) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.getChildAt(j);
        Log.e("DatasetTableLayout-data", tv.getText().toString() + " ");
    }
}
```

gives me:

```
01-24 11:03:31.668: ERROR/DatasetTableLayout-data(1624): activity1 
01-24 11:03:31.677: ERROR/DatasetTableLayout-data(1624): activity2 
01-24 11:03:31.698: ERROR/DatasetTableLayout-data(1624): activity3 
01-24 11:03:31.698: ERROR/DatasetTableLayout-data(1624): class1 
01-24 11:03:31.698: ERROR/DatasetTableLayout-data(1624): class2 
01-24 11:03:31.727: ERROR/DatasetTableLayout-data(1624): class3
```